# django administration : TabularInline as list

Tags: django, django-admin

I looking for a simple way or a package for making my tabularinline works as a list with pagination, number of item per page, filter, research and multiple selection (for delete action).

I have a model DiscountCode and DiscountCodeUsage and is possible that i have more than 1000 object DiscountCodeUsage for one DiscountCode and the standard tabularinline can't work for me.

Comment: Try to use [`django-inline-actions`](https://pypi.org/project/django-inline-actions/) package.

Comment: Hello and thank you, this does not answer my problem, I especially need pagination and research in addition to actions

Comment: Can you share your relevant code?